# Matrix operations in an Octave .oct file

Tags: for-loop, matrix, octave

I'd like to write concise code in a .oct file to perform matrix multiplication on the input column vector/matrix. The function internally creates, for example, a row vector A of 11 elements, and then within a loop I want to perform A * B where B is an 11 element sliding window down the input vector, writing the result to an output column vector/matrix as the loop progresses. I've tried various approaches using the information on http://wiki.octave.org/Tips_and_tricks but I can't get anything to compile - the error I'm getting is:

error: cannot convert ‘Matrix’ to ‘double’ in assignment

the relevant part of my code is:-

```
Matrix price = args(0).matrix_value () ; // a single column matrix
Matrix output = args(0).matrix_value () ;

// create intermediate calculation matrices
Matrix vec_11 (1,11) ;
Matrix price_11 (11,1) ;
Matrix result (1,1) ;

for ( int ii = -m ; ii < (m+1) ; ii ++ )
 {
 vec_11 is filled in this loop and then doesn't change  
 }

for ( octave_idx_type ii (50) ; ii < args(0).length () ; ii++ )
 {
 // extract rolling window and perform matrix multiplication
 result = vec_11 * price.extract(ii-10,0,ii,0) ;
 output(ii,1) = result ; // this writing to output matrix fails
 }

retval_list(0) = output ;
```

I am using matrix values for price, vec_11, result and output because I'm trying to do matrix multiplication, so I don't understand why I'm getting this conversion to double error. If I change price and output to column_vector_value and vec_11 to RowVector I still get the same error. It seems that

```
result = vec_11 * price.extract(ii-10,0,ii,0) ;
```

is giving a matrix_value but I can't write it to either a matrix_value or a column_vector_value output.

Comment: Are you sure that's the code you're compiling? The error you mention doesn't match with the code you showing. Can you show us the exact thing and minimum example that reproduces the error? By the way, if you have only a single column/row, you should use the 'RowVector' and 'ColumnVector' classes, not 'Matrix'.

Comment: @carandraug You're right - sloppy copying and pasting on my part. Have edited question to show the correct compile error and added some extra information in response to your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With help from [a mailing list](http://octave.1599824.n4.nabble.com/Matrix-like-operations-in-a-oct-file-td4657812.html) I have finally been able to solve my problem:

```
output(ii) = result( 0 , 0 ) ; // assign from indexed result matrix to output
```